# Find the values of the real parameter $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to find the values of the real parameter $k$ for which the equation: 
$$x^2-7x+2k+3=0$$
has roots with different signs.
We need the condition $x_1x_2<0$ for the roots to be with different signs. Using Vieta's formulas: $x_1+x_2=-\frac{b}{a}=-\frac{-7}{1}=7$ and $x_1x_2=\frac{c}{a}=\frac{2k+3}{1}=2k+3.$ As I said $x_1x_2<0$, so $2k+3<0, k<-\frac{3}{2}$. Is this the correct solution and should I write the first Vieta's formula ($x_1+x_2=-\frac{b}{a}$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't forget the discriminant should be  positive to ensure the existence of roots, so:$$49-4(2k+3)>0$$

Comment: But can't the discriminant be equal to $0$?

Comment: In that case both solution are the same so they have the same sign

Comment: But is $k<\frac{37}{8}$ the first constraint I should describe? Or it doesn't matter if I first write $k<-\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Demand $B^2>4AC$ and $C/A=2k+3<0$ for the roots of $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$, when $A,B,C$ are real. Here, you get $k<37/8$ and $k<-3/2$. The overlap of these two conditions is the answer:
$$k<-3/2$$

Answer (score 1):

It is east to overthink and overcomplicate this.

If you sketch the function, the parameter $k$ represents a vertical shift. So you want to identify the value of $k$ which gives $x=0$ as a solution and then if you drop the curve below that (shift it down) you will have roots with both signs.

ie the condition reduces to $f(0)\lt 0$ for $f(x)=x^2-7x+2k+3$ (note that the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive)

and that is what you get from the vieta product formula - you don't need the other one.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I haven't studied functions, but I want to see what they are. Can you tell me a tool with which I can sketch the function? I have tried to enter the equation in WolframAlpha but I didn't get graph.

Comment: @Valeri my main tool is a pen/pencil and paper, but then I'm old-fashioned. It is a simple parabola (quadratic).

Comment: Oh, sorry then. But when I enter the equation $x^2-7x+2k+3=0$ in WolframAlpha I don't get anything. Is this what I have to enter?

Comment: Enter $plot\ x^2 -7x$ and see what the graph looks like. Then try $plot\ x^2 -7x +C$ for various values of C (some positive, some negative) and see what happens to the graph. The solutions are the intersections of the graph with the x-axis.